# Have N elemnts of sum of a list and repeat until the end of the list

Tags: c#

I'm facing a problem when trying to play with C# list. Currently I have a list of integer. And I'm looking for a way to sum up every 5 integer, until the end of the list.
For example I have a list like this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

How to sum up every N elements (let's say 5) in the list and become:

```
[ 15, 40 ]
```

FYI, the list consist of hundred and thousand int elements.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Did you try a simple loop to sum up into a variable, and for every 5 values added to it, add the sum to a new list and reset it to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since noone's mentioned the simple way yet...

Note that if the input is not divisible by the group size, any extra elements will be ignored. For example, if the input is 11 elements, and the group size is 5, this will give 2 sums of 5 elements and then ignore the 11th input element.

```
public static int[] SumEvery(int[] input, int groupSize)
{
    // The number of groups we have
    int numGroups = input.Length / groupSize;
    int[] result = new int[numGroups];
    
    // For each group of numbers...
    for (int group = 0; group < numGroups; group++)
    {
        // ... loop through each number in that group, adding to the sum ...
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++)
        {
            sum += input[group * groupSize + i];            
        }
        // ... then store that sum in our array of results
        result[group] = sum;
    }
    
    return result;
}

int[] input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int[] result = SumEvery(input, 5);
```

If you want to stream the results as an `IEnumerable<int>`, rather than collecting them all into an array, then:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> SumEvery(int[] input, int groupSize)
{
    int numGroups = input.Length / groupSize;
    
    for (int group = 0; group < numGroups; group++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++)
        {
            sum += input[group * groupSize + i];            
        }
        yield return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: First solution ignores the last values if less than 5 elements remain after group division

Comment: @lorenzozane Both solutions do, and that's deliberate

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This method is also work perfectly!

Comment: @Hooix1123 please use this one if you have a large dataset!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a bit of Linq

```
var ints = new []{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    
var result = ints.Select((x,i) => new{Num = x,Index = i}) // Project to a list with the index and number
                 .GroupBy (i => i.Index/5)                // group by the int division by 5
                 .Select(g => g.Sum(a => a.Num));         // sum the numbers in each group
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BabP5N

Note that is is by *far* the least efficient way - and with a large data set will not perform well. But for a small dataset will work fine. This code is possibly the clearest interpretation of the problem.

Comment: With hundreds of thousands of elements, all of those new anonymous objects are probably adding unnecessary cost, and the need to maintain a hash table that large just to take every group of 5 consecutive elements is unnecessary

Comment: @canton7 Yeah you're right of course. But the code is nice and easy ;)